# Call Fragment method from activity using FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

Originally I had a single fragment loaded in my `MainActivity`class. I used the following in

> onCreate

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(new TimeTableFragment(), TIMETABLEFRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
        }
```

and in

> onResume

```
if(*setting has changed*){
 TimeTableFragment tf = (TimeTableFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(TIMETABLEFRAGMENT_TAG);
            if (null != tf) {
                tf.onStudentIdChanged();
            }
}
```

The `onStudentIdChanged()` method would refresh the fragment data as preference settings have changed.

I have now refactored this activity to use `FragmentPagerAdapter`and load two different fragments in tabs. Both fragments are instances of the same `TimetableFragment` class, but with different parameters passed when creating.

> FragmentPagerAdapter methods

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a Fragment
        switch (position) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
                return TimeTableFragment.newInstance(position);
            case 0:
                //todo add the single day here
                return TimeTableFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

> TimetableFragment Method

```
 public static TimeTableFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        TimeTableFragment fragment = new TimeTableFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Now that this is working, in `onResume` of my `MainActivity`I am no longer able to access the Fragments using `findFragmentByTag`, as they are not added in this way during `onCreate`and I can no longer call the `onStudentIdChanged` method.

How, for all created instances of the Timetable Fragment can I call this method and have the data updated / refreshed?

Comment: You should make the Fragments "subscribe" to an event, not explicitly "call out" for an update from the Activity. This is called the Observer Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In your `FragmentPagerAdapter` imprementation, add `private SparseArray<Fragment> mFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();`

Modify your getItem method as follows:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a Fragment
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        fragment = mFragments.get(position);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = TimeTableFragment.newInstance(position);
            mFragments.append(position, fragment)
        }
        break;
        case 0:
        //todo add the single day here
        fragment = mFragments.get(position);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = TimeTableFragment.newInstance(position);
            mFragments.append(position, fragment)
        }
        break;
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

Now when you can get instance of fragment by position.